# Why can't I use `using` in a multiple inheritance c++?

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

I tried to implement some interfaces and their children. This is my idea:

```
         Interface
         /       \
  Interface2    InterfaceDefination
        |        /
  Interface2Defination
```

And this is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Interface {
public:
  virtual void method1() = 0;
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public Interface {
public:
  virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class InterfaceDefination : public Interface {
public:
  virtual void method1() override {
    std::cout << "method1 from InterfaceDefination\n";
  }
};

class Interface2Defination : public Interface2, public InterfaceDefination {
public:
  using InterfaceDefination::method1;
  virtual void print() override {
    std::cout << "print from Interface2Defination\n";
  }
  virtual void method2() override {
    std::cout << "method2 from Interface2Defination\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Interface2Defination c;
  c.method1();
  c.method2();
  c.print();
}
```

My expected output is:

```
method1 from InterfaceDefination
method2 from Interface2Defination
print from Interface2Defination
```

But accidentally i received these errors:

```
main.cpp:33:24: error: variable type 'Interface2Defination' is an abstract class
  Interface2Defination c;
                       ^
main.cpp:5:16: note: unimplemented pure virtual method 'method1' in 'Interface2Defination'
  virtual void method1() = 0;
               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1
exit status 2
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9ncoGfn4P

In this case, the error means `using` keyword is not making method `method1` usable in class `Interface2Defination`. What should i do with it?

Comment: Your code form an *Y* (i.e your class have 2 distinct `Interface` ) not a *diamond* (which requires virtual inheritance).

Comment: You want a diamond-pattern inheritance architecture. Both Interface2 and InterfaceDefinition should inherit from Interface virtually. E.g. `class Interface2 : virtual public Interface ` and `class InterfaceDefination : virtual public Interface` . That ties both bases to the same root `Interface`, and thus the `using` will stick to the one (and only) `method1` root pure decl.

Comment: You are inheriting twice from Interface. Are you sure this is what you intend to do?

Comment: You can get detailed information about "using" keyword at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038898/applying-using-keyword-on-c-pure-virtual-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `using` declaration is a ***declaration***. It is not a ***definition***. It does not define anything "new". What it does is declare: ok, I have a symbol X, but it really refers to X in my parent class (for this version of a `using` declaration).

You might ask what's the point, aren't you inheriting X from your parent class in the normal fashion. Yes, that's true, but it's not the same thing, but the technical differences are mostly immaterial here.

What's also important here is that the shown diagram is misleading. It is a popular way to portray (non-virtual) diamond inheritance, but every time it's shown, it is 100% wrong. This is because `Interface2Defination` does not inherit ***one*** instance of `Interface`, but ***two***. This is a more accurate inheritance diagram:

```
  Interface          Interface
       |                |
  Interface2    InterfaceDefination
        |        /
  Interface2Defination
```

For each one of the two instances of `Interface` parent classes, only ***one*** of its abstract methods gets defined and overridden, hence the shown code is ill-formed.

The `using` declaration does not ***define*** the imported method in the child class, and formally override it. A `using` declaration does not "count" for the purpose of overriding an abstract method. Only formally defining an inherited abstract method does that, not declaring one.

Comment: The "100% wrong" portrayal is because it shows the OOP inheritance structure, but not the C++ layout which clearly shows that the CLASS inheritance is resulting in two separate class INSTANTIATIONS.  I concur with it being "100% wrong" because it causes confusion.  Curse you UML!

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, there are two `Interface::method1`s in `Interface2Defination`, and only one of them has an implementation. If you virtually inherit `Interface`, you have one, with a definition.

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface {
public:
  virtual void method1() = 0;
  virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Interface2 : public virtual Interface {
public:
  virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class InterfaceDefination : public virtual Interface {
public:
  virtual void method1() override {
    std::cout << "method1 from InterfaceDefination\n";
  }
};

class Interface2Defination : public Interface2, public InterfaceDefination {
public:
  virtual void print() override {
    std::cout << "print from Interface2Defination\n";
  }
  virtual void method2() override {
    std::cout << "method2 from Interface2Defination\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Interface2Defination c;
  c.method1();
  c.method2();
  c.print();
}
```